# How to add auto incremented columns while creating External Tables using CETAS in Azure Synapse serverless SQL Pool?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, serverless, azure-synapse

In server-less SQL Pool, Identities are not supported, is there any better way to add an auto-incremented column while creating an external table using Select Statement.

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.example_table
    WITH 
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = data_source_name,
        LOCATION = 'TempTables/exanple_table',
        FILE_FORMAT = parquet_file_format
    )
    AS 


    SELECT  name                                    AS user_name
         , code                                        AS user_code
      FROM schema.example_table
```

How can we add an auto-increment column along with the name and code column in external table?

I want something like -

| id | user_name | user_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Indrajeet | SinghI |
| 2 | Himanshu | RawatH |
| 3 | Akshay | SharmaA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ROW_NUMBER:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.example_table
    WITH 
    (
        DATA_SOURCE = data_source_name,
        LOCATION = 'TempTables/exanple_table',
        FILE_FORMAT = parquet_file_format
    )
    AS 


    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code) as id
         , name                                    AS user_name
         , code                                        AS user_code
      FROM schema.example_table
```

One warning. If you run the same tomorrow it won’t necessarily be the same id for Akshay. So this may not be appropriate except for a one-time load.

If stability cross days is important you might try `HASHBYTES('MD5', code) as id`. On a small table that should be unique. But on a large table you may have hash collisions and it not be unique.